# Reverse for 'quote-new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

I see there are a lot of similar posts on this. Please let me know if I should look at one in particular. I have gone through a bunch of them but don't see the error in my code.

For my code, I am following this tutorial: http://effectivedjango.com/tutorial/additional-views.html

My project's name is "triSpace". I'm running Django 1.6

**Error Message:**

```
Reverse for 'quote-new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0   pattern(s) tried: []
```

**triSpace/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import triSpace.views
from triSpace import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^event/$', views.event, name='event'),
url(r'^event/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', views.eventdetail, name='eventdetail'),
url(r'^virtue/$', views.virtue, name='virtue'),
url(r'^mapping/$', views.mapping, name='mapping' ),
url(r'^quotelist/$', triSpace.views.ListQuoteView.as_view(), name='quote-list'),
url(r'^quotenew/$', triSpace.views.CreateQuoteView.as_view(), name ='quote-new'),
url(r'^quoteedit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', triSpace.views.UpdateQuoteView.as_view(), name='quote-    edit'),
url(r'^quotedelete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', triSpace.views.DeleteQuoteView.as_view(), name='quote-delete'),)
```

**triSpace/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from triSpace.models import *
from django import forms
from triSpace.forms import EventModelForm, LocationModelForm
from gmapi import maps
from gmapi.forms.widgets import GoogleMap
from django.views.generic import View, ListView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView

class ListQuoteView(ListView):
    model = Quote
    template_name = 'triSpace/quote_list.html'

class CreateQuoteView(CreateView):
    model = Quote
    template_name = 'triSpace/edit_quote.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('triSpace:quote-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateQuoteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('quote-new')
    return context


class UpdateQuoteView(UpdateView):
    model = Quote
    template_name = 'triSpace/edit_quote.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('triSpace:quote-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UpdateQuoteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('triSpace:quote-edit',
                                kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().id})
        return context


class DeleteQuoteView(DeleteView):
    model = Quote
    template_name = 'triSpace/delete_quote.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('triSpace:quote-list')
```

**quote_list.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    Some content
<ul>
    {% for quote in object_list %}
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ quote }}
        (<a href="{% url "triSpace:quote-edit" pk=quote.id %}">edit</a>)
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<a href="{% url "triSpace:quote-new" %}">Submit Another Quote</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**edit_quote.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <ul>
        {% for quote in object_list %}
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ quote }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if quote.id %}
        <h1>Edit Quote</h1>
        {% else %}
        <h1>Add Quote</h1>
        {% endif %}
        <form action="{{ action }}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <ul>{{ form.as_ul }}</ul>
            <input id="save_quote" type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
        {% if quote.id %}
        <a href="{% url "triSpace:quote-delete" pk=quote.id %}">Delete Quote</a>
        {% endif %}
        <a href="{% url "triSpace:quote-list" %}">back to list</a>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Steps to get this error:
On the "quote-list" page when I click the link "Submit Another Quote", I get the error mentioned at the top of this post. It's the only action that throws an error, all other actions within this code are working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change up your urls.py to use name spaces (app_name is optional in this use case). Also, if you are just pulling in views from one views container, you can specify a prefix in

```
urlpatterns = patterns('triSpace.views',
```

as such,

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import triSpace.views

urlpatterns = patterns('triSpace.views',
    url(r'^event/$', event, name='event', namespace='triSpace', app_name='triSpace'),
    url(r'^event/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', eventdetail, name='eventdetail', namespace='triSpace', app_name='triSpace'),
    url(r'^virtue/$', virtue, name='virtue', namespace='triSpace', app_name='triSpace'),
    url(r'^mapping/$', mapping, name='mapping', namespace='triSpace', app_name='triSpace'),
    url(r'^quotelist/$', ListQuoteView.as_view(), name='quote-list', namespace='triSpace', app_name='triSpace'),
    url(r'^quotenew/$', CreateQuoteView.as_view(), name ='quote-new', namespace='triSpace', app_name='triSpace'),
    url(r'^quoteedit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UpdateQuoteView.as_view(), name='quote-edit', namespace='triSpace', app_name='triSpace'),
    url(r'^quotedelete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DeleteQuoteView.as_view(), name='quote-delete'),, namespace='triSpace', app_name='triSpace')
```

And whenever you reference a URL you use the form

```
reverse('triSpace:quote-list')
```

which is reverse(namespace:name)

Comment: This looks like it will work but I didn't include the homepage URL which is outside the namespace. How would I adjust your code to handle that? Just do urlpatterns += ?

Comment: Ok - when I try your corrections, I get an error in the browser that says "name event is not defined". Do I need to add a prefix to the second parameter in each of these URL patterns?

Comment: @BrianKempf did you use `{% url triSpace:event %}`? Also try taking out the app_name, that may be unnecessary.

Comment: Yup - that was my problem. Wow, silly mistake. Thanks for your help.